# React Native - Expo Audio stop all sounds

Tags: react-native, expo, audio-player

I am using [Expo Audio](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio.html) to play some short sounds from a list.

```
async playAudio(file) {

    try {
        await Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true);
        const sound = new Audio.Sound();
        await sound.loadAsync(file);
        await sound.playAsync(); 
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Which I'm calling from a list rendered with `list.map()`

```
renderTheList = (item, i) => {
    return (
        <View key={i}> 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => { this.onAudioSelected(item.audio) }}>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

onAudioSelected(audio) {
    // Audio.clearSounds() <-- something like this
    playAudio(audio)

    ...
    }
```

The sounds play fine, but when I select the next item in the list, the previous sound does not stop.  So if I touch a bunch in a row, a bunch of sounds play at once.

**How can I stop all currently playing sounds?**

Comment: `Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(false);` this should stop every thing

Comment: @RaajNadar that just disables the Expo Audio API... Disabling and re-enabling doesn't sound like a good use of resources

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out that I should create the playback object in the constructor and use `unloadAsync()`

```js
constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);

      this.audioPlayer = new Audio.Sound();

    }

    playSound = async () => {
        try {
          await this.audioPlayer.unloadAsync()
          await this.audioPlayer.loadAsync(require("../soundfile.mp3"));
          await this.audioPlayer.playAsync();
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn("Couldn't Play audio", err)
        }
    }
```

The full documentation is found at [AV - Expo Documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/sdk/av.html)

Comment: How would I do that if I want to stop any other audio player instances? for example multiple component if one is playing, I want to stop it while starting the other?